# Tensorflow - Convolution Neural Net accuracy stuck

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to train a small Convolutional Neural Network using Tensorflow (three Conv layers followed by fully connected) for a multiclass classification problem. The graph is built with ease without any issues, and training starts as well but the results do not really make a lot of sense.

Some brief information pertaining to the data and the code is following:

- Data shape (format=NHWC): `(N, 1, 150, 3)`
- Target Data shape: `(N, 3)`

Below is the entire code I used:

```
# Hyperparameters:
training_iters = 50
learning_rate = 0.001
batch_size = 128

# Network Parameters:
n_classes = 3  # total classes

tf.reset_default_graph()

x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 1, 150, 3])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])

def conv2d(x, W, b, strides=1):
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, strides, strides, 1], padding='VALID')
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)
    return tf.nn.relu(x)

def maxpool2d(x, k=2):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1,1,k,1], strides=[1,1,k,1], padding='VALID')

# defining weights and biases
weights = {
    'wc1': tf.get_variable('W0', shape=(1,5,3,4), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'wc2': tf.get_variable('W1', shape=(1,4,4,8), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'wc3': tf.get_variable('W2', shape=(1,4,8,16), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'wd1': tf.get_variable('W3', shape=(1*16*16,12), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'out': tf.get_variable('W6', shape=(12, n_classes), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
}

biases = {
    'bc1': tf.get_variable('B0', shape=(4), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'bc2': tf.get_variable('B1', shape=(8), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'bc3': tf.get_variable('B2', shape=(16), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'bd1': tf.get_variable('B3', shape=(12), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'out': tf.get_variable('B4', shape=(n_classes), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
}

def conv_net(x, weights, biases):  
    # here we call the conv2d function we had defined above and pass the input image x, weights wc1 and bias bc1.
    conv1 = conv2d(x, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1'])
    # Max Pooling (down-sampling), this chooses the max value from a 2*2 matrix window and outputs a 14*14 matrix.
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2)

    # Convolution Layer
    # here we call the conv2d function we had defined above and pass the input image x, weights wc2 and bias bc2.
    conv2 = conv2d(conv1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'])
    # Max Pooling (down-sampling), this chooses the max value from a 2*2 matrix window and outputs a 7*7 matrix.
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)

    conv3 = conv2d(conv2, weights['wc3'], biases['bc3'])
    # Max Pooling (down-sampling), this chooses the max value from a 2*2 matrix window and outputs a 4*4.
    conv3 = maxpool2d(conv3, k=2)

    # Fully connected layer
    # Reshape conv3 output to fit fully connected layer input

    fc1 = tf.reshape(conv3, [-1, weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
    fc1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['wd1']), biases['bd1'])
    fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1)

    # Output, class prediction
    # finally we multiply the fully connected layer with the weights and add a bias term. 
    out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['out']), biases['out'])
    return out

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

pred = conv_net(x, weights, biases)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=y, logits=pred))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred,1), tf.argmax(y,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) 
    train_loss = []
    test_loss = []
    train_accuracy = []
    test_accuracy = []
    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./Logs/Output', sess.graph)
    for i in range(training_iters):
        for batch in range(len(train_X)//batch_size):
            batch_x = train_X[batch*batch_size:min((batch+1)*batch_size,len(train_X))]
            batch_y = train_y[batch*batch_size:min((batch+1)*batch_size,len(train_y))]    
            # Run optimization op (backprop).
                # Calculate batch loss and accuracy
            opt, loss, acc = sess.run([optimizer, cost, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
            #acc, loss = sess.run([accuracy, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})

        print(f"Iter: {str(i+1)} \nTrain Loss: {loss:.8}, Train Accuracy: {acc:.8}")

        # Calculate accuracy for test data
        test_acc,valid_loss = sess.run([accuracy,cost], feed_dict={x: test_X,y : test_y})
        train_loss.append(loss)
        test_loss.append(valid_loss)
        train_accuracy.append(acc)
        test_accuracy.append(test_acc)
        saved_path = saver.save(sess, './Logs/Output/my-model', global_step=i)
        print(f"Test  Loss: {valid_loss:.8},    Test Accuracy: {test_acc:.8}")
    summary_writer.close()
```

And the progress output of training is:

```
Iter: 1 
Train Loss: 1.8626448e-08, Train Accuracy: 1.0
Test  Loss: 4.4217701,    Test Accuracy: 0.77379447
Iter: 2 
Train Loss: 9.3132252e-10, Train Accuracy: 1.0
Test  Loss: 4.3212051,    Test Accuracy: 0.77379447
Iter: 3 
Train Loss: 1.1455266e-07, Train Accuracy: 1.0
Test  Loss: 3.8599913,    Test Accuracy: 0.77379447
Iter: 4 
Train Loss: 1.5655376e-05, Train Accuracy: 1.0
Test  Loss: 4.6927552,    Test Accuracy: 0.77379447
Iter: 5 
Train Loss: 1.5967382e-05, Train Accuracy: 1.0
Test  Loss: 2.5689926,    Test Accuracy: 0.77379447
Iter: 6 
Train Loss: 0.00015663292, Train Accuracy: 1.0
Test  Loss: 2.0523434,    Test Accuracy: 0.77379447
Iter: 7 
Train Loss: 0.0017181182, Train Accuracy: 1.0
Test  Loss: 1.8788136,    Test Accuracy: 0.77379447
Iter: 8 
Train Loss: 4.656612e-09, Train Accuracy: 1.0
Test  Loss: 7.2591481,    Test Accuracy: 0.77379447
Iter: 9 
Train Loss: 7.4859377e-06, Train Accuracy: 1.0
Test  Loss: 3.1993084,    Test Accuracy: 0.77379447
Iter: 10 
Train Loss: 0.00010431254, Train Accuracy: 1.0
Test  Loss: 2.1976376,    Test Accuracy: 0.77379447
Iter: 11 
Train Loss: 0.0025378512, Train Accuracy: 1.0
Test  Loss: 1.5550417,    Test Accuracy: 0.77379447
Iter: 12 
Train Loss: 0.0010065944, Train Accuracy: 1.0
Test  Loss: 1.6730684,    Test Accuracy: 0.77379447
Iter: 13 
Train Loss: 0.00052482914, Train Accuracy: 1.0
Test  Loss: 1.8188649,    Test Accuracy: 0.77379447
Iter: 14 
Train Loss: 0.00013962867, Train Accuracy: 1.0
Test  Loss: 2.2431495,    Test Accuracy: 0.77379447
Iter: 15 
Train Loss: 0.00098675233, Train Accuracy: 1.0
Test  Loss: 2.0452898,    Test Accuracy: 0.77379447
```

Here, the losses start to behave normally after some iterations and steadily start going down and probably could be made better by experimenting with parameters. Though the problem is with accuracies, both, training and test as they are stuck. What exactly could be causing this? Possibly because of the way I'm calculating `correct_prediction` or `pred`, I guess.. How can this be resolved?

I am currently new in deep learning and all and still trying to figure out how things go about using low-level APIs. So, pardon my naivety. Any sort of help is really appreciated!

Comment: Just a suggestion: before delving with the low-level APIs, build the network with the high-level ones (Keras above all), see if that behaves as you expect and only then, if you are still interested, delve deeper in a lower-level API. That way, you'll know whether the problem is in your implementation, or just in the capacity of the network to learn your dataset. And you may also realise on the way that, perhaps, high-level APIs are actually just what you need.

Comment: Yes, I thought mentioning that wouldn't be necessary but I have worked on Keras for quite some time, I've even worked on PyTorch for months and CoreML as well, and things worked fine. I've just shifted to Tensorflow because of it giving a lot more control and being more mature in terms of deployment. So, this is probably the start of my journey with Tensorflow and I need a helping hand in it! :)

Comment: You can try including more convolutional layers before max-pooling layers.

Comment: Will try this.. But @ShubhamPanchal you mean, there isn't any issue with the code and the graph architecture that is causing my train and test accuracies to be stuck?